# Killing Stanford core nlp process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, stanford-nlp

I launch Stanford Core NLP server using the following command (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

I would like to kill this server once I am done using it. Simply closing terminal does not help. It does not release memory. Is there way to kill it and release memory without rebooting computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always `CTRL-C` in the terminal window to stop the server.

You could also `ps aux | grep StanfordCoreNLPServer` to find the pid and then kill the process manually.

When the server is started it should create a shutdown key and you can send that message to the server to close the server.  This isn't working on my Macbook Pro (maybe a permission issue ??) but I've seen it work on other machines.

Here is the command:

```
wget "localhost:9000/shutdown?key=`cat /tmp/corenlp.shutdown`" -O -
```

Note the shutdown key is stored at `/tmp/corenlp.shutdown`

If you use the the `-server_id server0` option the shutdown key will be stored at this path `/tmp/corenlp.shutdown.server0`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to kill the process. You can use lsof command.

```
#install lsof if missing
sudo apt install lsof
```

You can find the pid of CoreNLP using

```
lsof -i:9000
```

Replace 9000 with the port you used to run the server.

The output looks like

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    15867 XXXX   XXX  IPv6 XXXXXX      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
```

Use the pid from here and run.

```
kill 15867
```

PID of my server process is 15867.