# An elegant way to shut down the Stanford CoreNLP server on macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, stanford-nlp

After nearly 2 years, I still find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826851/killing-stanford-core-nlp-process/43826936#43826936) unsolved... Using `CTRL-C` does not help beacuse:

1. I can still interact with the server at `http://localhost:9000/`
2. Memory (usually 1GB+) is not freed at all

In addition, the shutdown key is nowhere to be found on my system. I'm using **stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05** on a Mac, but nothing can be found at `/tmp/corenlp.shutdown`. Is this a permission issue?

The only workaround seems to be using the snippet `ps aux | grep StanfordCoreNLPServer` provided by [@StanfordNLPHelp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4793732/stanfordnlphelp), and manually kill the process. However, is there a better way to do so?

Comment: The official way (doesn't work on macOS) to stop the Stanford CoreNLP Server is [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#stopping-the-server).

Comment: How are you starting the server ?  We have a new Python library out that has functions for starting the server.  If you start the server with a context manager it should get killed automatically when the Python code is done.